# How to get result from UploadValuesAsync - WebClient C#

Tags: c#, php, android, web-services

I'm doing on a Xamarin Android app and I have a class with bunch of methods for interaction with web service. Every of these methods should return something (true/false to be sure if the database transaction is completed or some other data from database). For example, I have a method:

```
public bool AddNewUser(User user)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Uri url = new Uri(web + "AddNewUser.php");
    NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
    bool result = false;

    parameters.Add("FirstName", user.FirstName);
    parameters.Add("LastName", user.LastName);
    parameters.Add("Email", user.Email);
    parameters.Add("MobileNumber", user.MobileNumber);

    client.UploadValuesAsync(url, parameters);
    client.UploadValuesCompleted += (object sender, UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs e) =>
    {
          if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result) == "true")
          {
               result = true;
          }
    };

    return result;
}
```

This method returns the result as true or false(if the transaction is completed or if the transaction is not completed).

This is my PHP file:

```
<?php

     require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/Connection.php');

     if(isset($_POST['FirstName']) && isset($_POST['LastName']) && isset($_POST['Email']) && isset($_POST['MobileNumber']))
     {
         $firstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
         $lastName = $_POST['LastName'];
         $email = $_POST['Email'];
         $mobileNumber = $_POST['MobileNumber'];

         $connection = new Connection();
         $connection->GetConnection();

         if(!$connection->conn)
         {
             echo 'Error: '.mysqli_connect_error();
         }
         else
         {
             $sql = 'INSERT INTO tb_user(name,lastname,mail,phone) VALUES ("'.$firstName.'","'.$lastName.'","'.$email.'","'.$mobileNumber.'")';
             $result = mysqli_query($connection->conn,$sql);

             if(!$result)
             {
                  echo 'Error: '.mysqli_error($connection->conn);
             }
             else
             {
                  echo true;
             }
         }
     }

?>
```

But app crashes with no error and also user is not added. Now, I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

Error in UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs is equal to null. Is then something wrong with my PHP file?

**UPDATE 2:**
So, I used only UploadValues instead of UploadValuesAsync,like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Uri url = new Uri(web + "AddNewUser.php");
NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
bool result = false;

parameters.Add("FirstName", user.FirstName);
parameters.Add("LastName", user.LastName);
parameters.Add("Email", user.Email);
parameters.Add("MobileNumber",user.MobileNumber);

byte[] r = client.UploadValues(url,parameters);
if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(r) == "true")
{
       result = true;
}

return result;
```

In android device logging this error is written:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: How about add try-catch block in that method ? Otherwise, unhandled exception can you see it in event viewer.

Comment: From the output I cannot say clearly what is the problem

Comment: Paste the exception message from try-catch block, otherwise is really hard to examine unknown exception.

Comment: I pasted whole debug output

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: Debug it one by one. Use UploadValues first, without async. Add try-catch block both in C# and PHP. and see what happen.